# Input Autofill Caret Missing

Tags: javascript, html, css, autofill

The caret (blinking text input cursor thing) is missing when the form uses autocomplete.

When you click into the input field there is no caret. Once you add or remove a character from the field the autocomplete styling goes away and the cursor comes back.

There are a lot of questions and answers about removing the blue background color in autofilled forms, but I haven't found any good answers about the caret. Is there a way to get the caret to show up?

For context. I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 if that effects anything.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @FilipNilsson Unfortunately I haven't found a solution for this yet.

Comment: This still happens in Chrome 107 on Mac. Maybe it is intended behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a caret-color to autofilled input

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
   caret-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use id="email"

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" id="LoginUser" />
```